# TreeView QML Error - QVariant::QVariant(void*)' is private Within This context

Tags: c++, model, qml

I'm trying to set up the model for the treeView,( my model class inherits from QAbstractItemModel)

```
CardsTreeModel * myModel=new CardsTreeModel(file.readAll());


QObject * pTree = m_pQmlObject->findChild<QObject*>("cardsTreeView");
pTree->setProperty("model", myModel );
```

And got such errors:

```
qvariant.h:465: error: 'QVariant::QVariant(void*)' is private
     inline QVariant(void *) Q_DECL_EQ_DELETE;
cardchoice.cpp:27: error: within this context
  pTree->setProperty("model", myModel );
                                      ^
```

Help me please to resolve this problem!

Comment: `setProperty` takes `QVariant` as its second parameter. You are passing `CardsTreeModel*`, which cannot be implicitly converted to `QVariant`. You may be able to write `QVariant::fromValue(myModel)`. It's not clear what you are trying to achieve though; you seem to think that "model" is some special property name and assigning to it achieves some magical effect.

Comment: I sucsessfully set the model in this way in such example: QObject * pList = m_pQmlObject->findChild<QObject*>("devicesList");
 m_strListView.append("device");
 pList->setProperty("model",m_strListView);

Comment: `QVariant` has a constructor taking `QStringList`, which is what I imagine `m_strListView` is. Anyway, what you likely want is something like `qobject_cast<QAbstractItemView*>(pTree)->setModel(myModel);`

Comment: Igor, you gave me the right variant (first, qvariant fromvalue)! Model is transferd, but it seems the treeview in qml is incorrect, ant since i can see the right amount of the rows, it's empty

Comment: Well, that means your `CardsTreeModel` doesn't report the correct data to the view. Time to break out your trusty debugger, I suppose.

Comment: :) noo, it seems i just have fogoten a delegate in QML TreeView {
  id: cardsTreeView
  objectName:"cardsTreeView"
  TableViewColumn {
   title: "country"
   role: "country"
   width: 300
  }
  TableViewColumn {
   title: "action"
   role: "action"
   width: 100
  }
  model: MyModel
 }

Answer (score 1):

Is your myModel QObject? I have the same problem using class in C++ remember to add Q_OBJECT and qmake.